# Git Resolve issues automatically when committing code?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

is there a way to automatically resolves a issue when committing the fix file using git.

s**ay i have Issue #265 and i want to add json.js to branch name efeat , so the issue is fixed**

what would be the steps?. if any one can include all steps , including all the known steps like git add file name ..,git status  etc

Comment: This should help for GitHub https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to resolve an issue/issumes when commit changes:

1. As osowskit said, you can use **certain format for commit messages**. Such as you can use `resolve #265` for commit message, so the issue will be closed.
2. Use **commit-msg hook**. In the commit-msg hook, you can check if it’s commit for a certain file, a certain branch etc, if the changes is what you want to close an github issue, you can change the commit message as the format `close #265`, `fix #265` and `resolve #265` etc.